# Compile-time search in static-array

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

In a project, I have several classes which encapsulate, among other things, matrices implemented as static-arrays, e.g.:

```
struct StaticContainer
{
    static const short e[2][4];
};

/// Initialize components of member-array (with external linkage).
const short StaticContainer::e[2][4] = {
    { -1,  0, 0, 1 },
    {  0, -1, 1, 0 }
};
```

I would like to implement a meta-function which provides the inverse-mapping, from a column in StaticContainer::e back to the second index (1-4 in this case). Ideally, something like this:

```
template< typename TContainer, short TeX, short TeY >
struct VectorToIndex
{
    enum { value = ??? };
};
```

Finally, I would like to pass (if this is possible at all):

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( 0 == VectorToIndex< StaticContainer, -1, 0 >::value );
```

Is this possible at all? My initial attempts to recursively-search through the 'e'-matrix failed, because whenever I try to access (at compile-time) the entries within I get (GCC):

```
error: ‘StaticContainer::e’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

Shall I understand that the values in the matrix are not available at compile-time?

I would appreciate any comments. I am free to change the way the matrix is initialized/stored (so I was thinking of some compile-time registration mechanism). The only constraint is to get this inverse-mapping at compile-time.

**Clarifications:**

- Each column in the e-matrix represents a spatial direction (in this case, 2D). The columns are guaranteed to be distinct.
- I would expect the following results from the meta-function:

  ```
  VectorToIndex< StaticContainer, -1, 0 > --> '0' at compile-time
  VectorToIndex< StaticContainer,  0,-1 > --> '1' at compile-time
  VectorToIndex< StaticContainer,  0, 1 > --> '2' at compile-time
  VectorToIndex< StaticContainer,  1, 0 > --> '3' at compile-time
  ```

If this template is instantiated with an invalid combination of numbers (i.e. which is not a column in the matrix), I would like to produce a compilation-error.

- The solution I currently have is a simple program which writes files with the necessary template-instantiations manually. This satisfies the requirements (results are correct and for invalid vectors there is a compile-time error - since the corresponding template-instantiation is missing). However, since I have many classes similar to 'StaticContainer' in my codebase (many of them with larger matrices), this process generates thousands of lines of code :(.

Comment: You can't use mpl? If you could define the values in the array as integral constants, then you could use the existing `boost::mpl::vector` possibly?

Comment: I will look into this. Do you know if it is possible to store a matrix inside a boost::mpl::vector (as in std::vector<std::vector<int>>?)

Comment: @Dragos: Could you better define the inverse mapping, what if I supply `(0, 0)` as parameter ? Both `1` and `2` would be valid indices.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Thank you for your interest. I added some clarifications.

Comment: You can also work it out using variadic templates if you have access to a compiler which implements this feature. When I get home later this evening I'll try to show you how, that is, if nobody else does it till then.
From there it shouldn't be that hard to boostify it through mpl if c++03 compliance is required, though I must say I've never actually used mpl myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promissed, here goes a solution. Rather than reinventing a whole metaprogramming library using variadic templates, I used this opportunity to try out boost mpl and it turns out to be pretty expressive. Using it, VectorToIndex would look like the following:

```
template<typename basis, typename axis>
struct VectorToIndex : 
    boost::mpl::if_<
        boost::mpl::greater<boost::mpl::size<basis>, typename boost::mpl::find<basis, axis>::type::pos>,
        typename boost::mpl::find<basis, axis>::type::pos,
        boost::mpl::empty_base
    >::type
{
};
```

If "axis" is present in "basis" then `VectorToIndex<basis, axis>::value` equals its index in the range [0, size-of-basis). If otherwise this is not true, than `VectorToIndex<basis, axis>::value` is not defined, thus accessing it may be used to produce compile-time errors or 
selective instanciation through SFINAE.

To represent the axis one should use boost::mpl::vector, like shown below:

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector<boost::mpl::int_<1>, boost::mpl::int_<0>, boost::mpl::int_<0> > e1;
typedef boost::mpl::vector<boost::mpl::int_<0>, boost::mpl::int_<1>, boost::mpl::int_<0> > e2;
typedef boost::mpl::vector<boost::mpl::int_<0>, boost::mpl::int_<0>, boost::mpl::int_<1> > e3;
```

Considering the definitions above, one has

```
VectorToIndex<boost::mpl::vector<e1, e2, e3>, e1>::value -> 0
VectorToIndex<boost::mpl::vector<e1, e2, e3>, e2>::value -> 1
VectorToIndex<boost::mpl::vector<e1, e2, e3>, e3>::value -> 2
VectorToIndex<boost::mpl::vector<e1, e2>, e3>::value -> COMPILE-TIME ERROR
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! MPL is an amazing library indeed, and also the path I have chosen in the end (but forgot to post it - shame on me).

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch in your declarations:

- `typename TContainer` means that the template parameter is a type
- `StaticContainer::e` is a value

It cannot match.

There are a few potential solutions I can think of, but the first question is obviously: why not build the reverse matrix manually and use `assert` to prove its correctness ? It is certainly simpler, and simple is beautiful.

Comment: Regarding the mismatch: my intention was to also pass the container as a tparam to 'VectorToIndex', since I have many classes similar to 'StaticContainer' in the real code. This is also the reason why I would look for a meta-programming solution. For the moment, I have a simple program which generates (run-time) all the template-instantiations for these inverse-mappings, but the output is massive, and it also complicates the build-process.